# Difference in Equation Output

Tags: equations, numbering

Using the code below on the online renderer at http://quicklatex.com/:

```
\begin{align}
\ddot{\underline{\mathbf{r}}} &= \frac{d{^2}\underline{\mathbf{r}}}{dt^2}\\
                              &= 0
\end{align}
```

I get:

[image: Individual Equation Numbering]

This is what i want.

But then I use the same code in Wordpress with QuickLaTex plugin as follows:

```
[latexpage]
\begin{align}
\ddot{\underline{\mathbf{r}}} &= \frac{d{^2}\underline{\mathbf{r}}}{dt^2}\\
                              &= 0
\end{align}
```

I get:

[image: Wordpress Output]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I made soem tests in math.stackexchange environment (that uses mathjax).

The result is that the second (unexpected) output is possibly comes from mathjax automatic convertion like:

```
$\begin{align}
\ddot{\underline{\mathbf{r}}} &= \frac{d{^2}\underline{\mathbf{r}}}{dt^2}\\
                                  &= 0
\end{align}\tag{1}$
```

PS: such command can not work on real LaTeX but may be can be an automated conversion that can be used in mathjax to avoid real latex need.

To test it you can add a tikzpicture or something before the command to see if it really using latex or mathjax... and if the result of the picture is the same.

PS: not really an answer but not a comment too. Just a guess that needs space to be written.

Comment: Hi for mathjax in Wordpress I use
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  TeX: { equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "AMS" } }
});
</script>

[mathjax]
\begin{align}
\ddot{\underline{\mathbf{r}}} &= \frac{d{^2}\underline{\mathbf{r}}}{dt^2}\\
                                  &= 0
\end{align}

Comment: Hi... I don't use mathjax... I just tried to understand and explain ehat is going on... Just a guess because this output (your second) is not a latex output of your code...